# Youtube App Version 4.0.8E crashes on open

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, youtube, htc-one-x

I am using an HTC One X on UK network Orange, unrooted.

The latest update to the Youtube App ( version 4.0.8E) crashes on launch every time. If I uninstall updates to go back to the pre-installed version then it works fine, so it seems a safe assumption the new update is causing this.

Is there anything I can do other than wait for the app authors to resolve it?

I have a LogCat file linked here:- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1159676/StackExchange/YouTube%204.08E%20logcat.txt

Rob

Answer (score 1):

This can sometimes happen during an upgrade if old, incompatible data or config is stuck in the app's storage.

Have you tried clearing the data and cache on the Youtube app?

Go into your phone's **Settings** -> **Apps** -> **All** scroll all the way down to the YouTube app and tap it.

You should now be on a screen showing all kinds of info about the YouTube app, <kbd>Force Stop</kbd> the YouTube app if its still running, then about half-way down should be a <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd> button. Press the <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd> button and then try launching the YouTube app again to see if it fixes the problem.

If not then go back into Settings -> Apps -> YouTube, ensure YouTube is stopped (with a Force Stop) and then try both the <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd> and <kbd>Clear Data</kbd> buttons and try launching YouTube again.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make any difference. Even clearing the data and cache the program closes on launch.